# How to duplicate PowerPoint files in python?

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

#### Problem:

I'm trying to duplicate a slide from a presentation to another presentation, but it returns error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
> File "C:\Users\vuse1\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\PythonApplication\PythonApplication\PythonApplication.py", line 8, in  
>  prs2.slides.add_slide(copySlide) 
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pptx\slide.py", line 287, in add_slide
>   slide.shapes.clone_layout_placeholders(slide_layout) 
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pptx\shapes\shapetree.py", line 515, in
>   clone_layout_placeholders for placeholder in slide_layout.iter_cloneable_placeholders():  
> AttributeError: 'Slide' object has no attribute 'iter_cloneable_placeholders'
> ```

#### Code:

```
from pptx import Presentation

prs1 = Presentation("C:\\Users\\vuse1\Desktop\\first.pptx")
prs2 = Presentation("C:\\Users\\vuse1\Desktop\\second.pptx")

copySlide=prs1.slides[0]

prs2.slides.add_slide(copySlide)

prs2.save("C:\\Users\\vuse1\Desktop\\second.pptx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying slides isn't officially supported by the library. There's a lot of discussion about this topic. Look at [this github issue](https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/132) for workarounds.